# App hangs when network connection is bad and AVPlayer is playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am devoloping a radio application for iOS. when the network connection is good, app is working fine.

My scenario is little different. I throttled the mobile data speed in iphone(Settings -> Developer -> Network Link Conditioner) and chose poor network option from the list. At this time, player is trying to stream the audio content and if i try to present or dismiss a view controller then either app slows or hangs. I tried to present the view controller from main queue but that didn't work.

```
   let requestedKey = ["playable","duration"]
            asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: requestedKey) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    var error: NSError?
                    let keyStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
                    if keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatus.failed || !asset.isPlayable {
                        completionHandler(false, nil)
                        return
                    }
                    completionHandler(true, asset)
                }
            }

if player == nil {
            player = AVPlayer()

        }
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
```

This is how i set the player. Please help me to resolve this serious performance issue when the connection is poor or edge.

Comment: Can you please share some code and show how you implemented this?  It sounds to me like you're doing network stuff on the main thread which blocks UI processes.

Comment: yes i have updated the question

Comment: Can you show me where you're initializing your player and loading the URL used for playback?

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot to do, to manage bad network connection and resume playback when using AVPlayer.

But it's not about a thread management.

When an `AVPlayerItem` failed: `AVPlayerItem.Status` == `.failed`, you must init a new `AVPlayerItem` object and inject to AVPlayer. you can use `replaceCurrentItem(with:)` AVPlayer method.

Also, to detect any playback failed situation, you can observe this notifications:

- `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled`
- `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` (trigged also when buffer is empty **AND** network out)
- `AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime`

You can check `[ModernAVPlayer][1]` library, specially PlayingState.swift file to understand the process.